# SVG in base64 to ImageSource (Maui/Xamarin)

Tags: c#, image, svg, maui

I'm making a MAUI app, using C# (no XAML)

I have an SVG that I converted to base64.

That base64 code is saved as a string.

I want to use that string as a the basis of an image source.

This code:

```
/// <summary>
        /// converts a base64 string into an imagesource as a png.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="imageString"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static ImageSource FromBase64ToPng(this string imageString)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageString);


            ImageSource? st = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                return new MemoryStream(bytes);
            });

            

            return st;
        }
```

works if the image is a PNG.

It doesn't crash if an SVG is provided, it doesn't even throw an error, but nothing shows up. I've checked that the data CAN be converted back into an image, and it can.

The only way I found to make it work is:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Converts a base64 encoded svg to file, then that file is used as an ImageSource. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <notes>
        /// Eamonn Alphin 2022/July/6: Created
        /// </notes>
        /// <param name="imageString">the base64 encoded svg</param>
        /// <param name="fileName">The name ot save the file as. lowercase, no spaces, alphanumeric only.</param>
        /// <returns>Image</returns>
        public static ImageSource FromBase64Tosvg(this string imageString, string fileName)
        {
            string xmlString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(imageString));
                
            
                string theFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), $"{fileName.ToLower()}.svg");//address
                File.WriteAllText(theFilePath, xmlString);
                ImageSource st = ImageSource.FromFile(theFilePath);
                return st;

        }
```

Where I basically CREATE the SVG file, but this doesn't FEEL right.

What am I missing? How can I pass an SVG, encoded in base64, to a memoryStream so I can create an ImageSource out of it?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6888

Comment: oh. well then. that's 1.5 days wasted.

Comment: @EamonnA Check my SVG image control that uses Skia instead of converting the image to a png to do this https://github.com/FreakyAli/MAUI.FreakyControls